# Particle system display

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am using the Three.js `ParticleSystem` for displaying a big number of points, providing a nice performance.

Depending on the zoom level, the particles can be very close to each other and this creates a set of strange De Moivre fringes when modifying the camera position.

The code for building this:

```
var material = new THREE.ParticleSystemMaterial({
    size : 250,
    color : colors[i]
});
parentMesh.add(new THREE.ParticleSystem(geometries[i], material));
```

There are 4 such particle system objects created, one of them has a red material and the other ones being green, blue and yellow.

Is there anything I can do for avoiding the De Moivre artifacts behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any screenshot / more code it's hard to say, what causes this effect. The size of your material is rather big, so first I would lower that. Then I would disable depthWrite for your material `colors: colors[i], depthWrite : false });`

I also would create one particle system that contains all your particles. So you push all your vertices into one geometry and set the color of this vertice by adding a colors array to the geometry. In your material you then set the colors to vertexColors. This way you have one big buffer and not 4 of them.

```
var myColors = [new THREE.Color(0xff0000),new THREE.Color(0x00ff00),new THREE.Color(0x0000ff),new THREE.Color(0xffff00)], //your predefined colors
    geometryColors = [];

for( var i = 0,j = geometry.vertices.length; i < j; i++ ) {

  geometryColors[i] = myColors[(i%myColors.length)-1].clone(); //put the color into the geometryColors array (not sure if you really have to clone it)

}

geometry.colors = geometryColors;

var material = new THREE.ParticleSystemMaterial({
  depthWrite : false,
  size : 5,
  vertexColors : THREE.VertexColors
});

parentMesh.add(new THREE.ParticleSystem(geometry, material));
```

Answer (score 0):

Without code and/or screenshots it's hard to say for certain, but it very much sounds like a case of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting. The way to combat this effect when geometry is overlapping is to ensure there's enough of a distance between the planes of geometry on the depth axis.